# Include records not matching WHERE criteria

Tags: sql-server

This works great. But I would also like to include items that have not sold in that date range. Currently is shows only items sold within the selected date range. I would like it to show the items that haven't sold as well.

```
SELECT i.item_number, i.item_name, ish.avg_cost, ish.avg_retail, ish.avg_daily_sales,
CASE WHEN i.sold_by_id = '0' THEN 'pcs'
     WHEN i.sold_by_id = '1' THEN 'lbs'
     WHEN i.sold_by_id = '2' THEN 'lbs'
END [Sold_by]
FROM inventory i
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ish.item_number, AVG(avg_cost) as avg_cost, AVG(avg_retail) as avg_retail, ROUND(AVG(total_sold),0) as avg_daily_sales 
    FROM inventory_sales_history ish
        LEFT JOIN Inventory i ON i.item_number = ish.Item_Number
WHERE ish.the_date BETWEEN '12-11-2016' AND '12-18-2016'
AND ish.item_number IN (SELECT item_number FROM inventory i JOIN department d ON d.department_id = i.department_id WHERE d.category_id = '4')
GROUP BY ish.item_number)ish
ON i.item_number = ish.item_number
ORDER BY i.item_name
```

**Update based on comments:**

An item that has sold is identified as one that's in the `inventory` table, but not in the `inventory_sales_history` table

Comment: how do you identify items that haven't sold?

Comment: If they're in the inventory table, but not in the inventory_sales_history table

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as DVT's answer in that it changes the join to the sub query from an inner join to a left join. I just refactored the query a bit while looking at it.

You might want to look into [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).

edit: moved the department join to the outer query

```
select 
     i.item_number
   , i.item_name
   , ish.avg_cost
   , ish.avg_retail
   , ish.avg_daily_sales
   , Sold_by = case 
          when i.sold_by_id = '0' then 'pcs' 
          when i.sold_by_id = '1' then 'lbs' 
          when i.sold_by_id = '2' then 'lbs' 
          end
  from inventory i
    inner join department d on d.department_id = i.department_id 
      and d.category_id='4'
    left join (
     select 
            ish.item_number
          , avg_cost = avg(avg_cost)
          , avg_retail = avg(avg_retail)
          , avg_daily_sales = round(avg(total_sold), 0)
        from inventory_sales_history ish 
        where ish.the_date between '12-11-2016' and '12-18-2016'
        group by ish.item_number
     ) as ish on i.item_number = ish.item_number
  order by i.item_name
```

Comment: Same as the other solution offered. Brings up all items. Ignores the category_id.

Comment: @user3556177 fixed that

Comment: @user3556177 - Definitely take a look at the link above. The tips on proper date handling can be applied to most any query with a date filter, not just this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT i.item_number, i.item_name, ish.avg_cost, ish.avg_retail, ish.avg_daily_sales,
CASE WHEN i.sold_by_id = '0' THEN 'pcs'
     WHEN i.sold_by_id = '1' THEN 'lbs'
     WHEN i.sold_by_id = '2' THEN 'lbs'
END [Sold_by]
FROM inventory i
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ish.item_number, AVG(avg_cost) as avg_cost, AVG(avg_retail) as avg_retail, ROUND(AVG(total_sold),0) as avg_daily_sales 
    FROM inventory_sales_history ish
        LEFT JOIN Inventory i ON i.item_number = ish.Item_Number
WHERE ish.the_date BETWEEN '12-11-2016' AND '12-18-2016'
AND ish.item_number IN (SELECT item_number FROM inventory i JOIN department d ON d.department_id = i.department_id WHERE d.category_id = '4')
GROUP BY ish.item_number)ish
ON i.item_number = ish.item_number
ORDER BY i.item_name
```

Comment: This didn't work. Brought up all inventory and ignored the category_id

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Your suggestions pointed me in the right directions.

```
SELECT i.item_number
      , i.item_name
      , ish.avg_cost
      , ish.avg_retail
      , ish.avg_daily_sales
      , CASE WHEN i.sold_by_id = '0' THEN 'pcs'
             WHEN i.sold_by_id = '1' THEN 'lbs'
             WHEN i.sold_by_id = '2' THEN 'lbs'
        END [Sold_by]
FROM inventory i LEFT JOIN 
         (
            SELECT ish.item_number
                  , AVG(avg_cost) as avg_cost
                  , AVG(avg_retail) as avg_retail
                  , ROUND(AVG(total_sold),0) as avg_daily_sales 
            FROM inventory_sales_history ish LEFT JOIN Inventory i 
                     ON i.item_number = ish.Item_Number
            WHERE ish.the_date BETWEEN '12-11-2016' AND '12-18-2016'
            GROUP BY ish.item_number
        ) 
        ish ON i.item_number = ish.item_number
WHERE  i.item_number IN 
       (
          SELECT item_number 
          FROM   inventory i JOIN department d 
                ON d.department_id = i.department_id 
          WHERE d.category_id = '4'
       )
ORDER BY i.item_name
```